# Apache Access denied after changing the web root permissions

Tags: apache, webserver

I recently changed the document root permissions to everyone using this command:

```
sudo chmod  -R 753 /var/www
```

But not when I access the website, I get the error.

You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.

I tried modifying the http.conf to allow access but nothing happened. Basically, how do i undo this command?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow access to apache user and group for your /var/www directory to work your sites. You need to assign 755 permission to your /var/www directory